# Pre-generate users for other people when you need it

Tags: user-expectation, accounts

I'm developing an app where the user A is able to take a list of her contacts, and to group them somehow into an event she organised. When she groups them, she's asked their email and their name.

Normally, **users should be in the same room as she** (because otherwise these events don't make sense), **but she can still add people that aren't there**.

After this, users could have access to the event user A created, and eventually might end up using the app to create their own events. The detail here is that **users don't need to enter into the app ever, for them to benefit from the event**.

The issue is there. They might never enter, but in case they ever use the app, they should have the historic information any user ever created.

Should I pre create user accounts, or should I block any kind of "event linking" until the specific user, let's say, accepts the user A's offer?

Comment: I am sorry... but I am not able to understand your question.
May be if you can attach the wireframes of screenshots to make it more comprehend.

Comment: Right now your question presents a problem that is specific to you only, and is not posed as a general UX question that would be helpful to the wider community.  Hence I am closing it as off topic, but if you find a way to make it a more general UX question, you can ask for it to be re-evaluated and possibly opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing people to create an account when they've been invited by another user is a sure fire way to annoy them.

If they've been invited by an authenticated user then you already have a favourable 'token' which you could allow them a certain amount of permissions without being fully registered.

So in my mind, a good user experience would be to allow them to respond to the event, but include gentle prompts to ask them to register, well extolling the benefits of doings so (i.e. create their own event et al)

Comment: What about if a basic User object for the invited person is created in our system after user A adds him, just to keep record of which events he did? A gentle email seems nice to me, but keeping an already unconfirmed account with a user's name and email shouldn't compromise somehow the user's privacy?

Comment: Ah, well I took that as a given, you can quietly create the user account in the background, but keep it in an 'unconfirmed' state

Comment: Well, that sounds fair to me! Here comes the tick